# How do I access elements from Json?

Tags: json, java

If I do
`String json = api.doRetrieve(endpoint);` then I get back a json string.

This is an array of objects.

How do I get it to where I can do `obj.someproperty` in Java and access it?

I'm doing this:

```
String json = api.doRetrieve(endpoint);
List<Object> allObjs = (List<Object>) System.JSON.deserializeUntyped(json);
List<Object> toPush = new List<Object>();
for(Object currObj : allObjs) {
    Map<String, Object> newObj = System.JSON.deserializeUntyped(currObj);
    toPush.add(newObj);
    System.debug((String)newObj.get('SFID'));
}
```

But it gives me a compilation error at the `Map` line. saying `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: System.JSON.deserializeUntyped(Object)`

For now I only care about one property: `SFID`.

My json is like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54ed139f28a35000000ead68"),
    "SFID" : "FUBARRING",
    "resourceURL" : "mywebsite.com",
    "customerName" : "nyan",
    "content" : [ 
        ObjectId("546264ac39dd3e10ee4071b5")
    ],
    "type" : "opp",
    "scenarios" : [],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

---

I got it to work doing this:

```
String json = api.doRetrieve(endpoint);
        String search = id;
        JSONParser parser = System.JSON.createParser(json);
        Boolean canAdd = true;
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if (parser.getText() == 'SFID') {
                parser.nextToken();
                if(id == parser.getText()){
                    System.debug('found id ' +id);    
                    canAdd=false;
                }
            }
        }
        if(canAdd){ // do some stuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your response is like this:

```
{ "objects":[
    {"someproperty":"foo","anotherproperty":"horse"},{"someproperty":"bar","anotherproperty":"staple"}
  ]
}
```

You would write your code to extract the properties like this:

```
String json = api.doRetrieve(endpoint);
Map < String, Object > jsonResp = (Map < String, Object > ) JSON.deserializeUntyped(json);

Object[] objects = (Object[]) jsonResp.get('objects');

for (Object obj: objects) {
    Map < String, Object > propMap = (Map < String, Object > ) obj;
    String someProperty = (String) propMap.get('someproperty');
}
```

I'm not totally sure of your JSON structure, but if you put it up, I can modify this example code to fit.

Also, there is a JSON parser that you can use which is pretty cool:

You'd go something like this:

```
String someProperty = "";
JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
    if (parser.getText() == 'someproperty') {
        parser.nextToken();
        someProperty = parser.getText();
        break;
    }
}

return someProperty;
```

Comment: I get a compilation error `unexpected token: 'Map'` at the second line

Comment: if you put your JSON up, I can modify the code to make it work for you. On the other hand, you could just use the second technique.

Comment: I've edited the question to include my json

Comment: I noticed that my Map definition is separated by spaces ie Map < String, Object >... Try removing the extra spaces - Map<String,Object>

Comment: Can you post your updated code as well so I can see what it looks like?

Comment: I got it to work by doing the second method. I'll update my code